# O que é a tecnologia SOAP?

Tags: web-service, soap, internet

Venho acompanhando um projeto (um site de noticias de um colégio) onde múltiplas linguagens (PHP para construir o site onde as noticias são colocadas e android, ios, c#, por onde elas serão acessadas por parte dos desenvolvedores do site como por usuários) são usadas para fazer praticamente a mesma aplicação, essas linguagens não são compatíveis entre si, mas precisam de um serviço (propósito comum), possuem um banco de dados com as mesmas entidades e todos precisam interagir com esse banco.

Há a necessidade de criar um *webservice*, onde todas as aplicações envolvidas (escritas em diferentes linguagens) podem buscar interagir com o banco de dados através de uma ponte ao invés de cada uma fazer isso diretamente do seu próprio modo.

Como solução fala-se em usar o SOAP, como essa tecnologia poderia ajudar? É a unica forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Que projeto seria este? Dê mais informações para pode ajudar melhor.

Comment: Não, atualmente existe tecnologias mais modernas como servidores REST, onde você pode ter um servidor de aplicações fará a conexão com o banco de dados e disponibilizara métodos para os clientes. Você deve dar uma estudada em arquiteturas modelos multicamadas, etc

Comment: @Artur_Indio  obrigado cara , você podia responder a pergunta são exatamente  esses métodos  que estou querendo ! Eu não conhecia o REST! Você podeira falar como o SOAP faria o mesmo? Que linguagem usa, quais métodos são abordados

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como comentei acima, existem outras maneiras de fazer o que vc precisa utilizando servidores REST, uma vantagem do REST, é que as camadas cliente podem ser desenvolvidas em qualquer linguagem de programação que possua suporte à JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).

O JSON tem sido bastante utilizado por aplicações web devido a sua capacidade de estruturar informações de uma forma bem mais compacta do que o modelo XML, tornando mais rápido o parsing (análise) dessas informações.

De forma geral os Web Services mencionados por vc vieram para permitir que aplicações desenvolvidas em diferentes linguagens, rodando sobre diferentes plataformas, pudessem trocar dados entre si de forma transparente. O protocolo SOAP de comunicação os dados são estruturados via XML.

Porém os Web Services utilizam SOAP sobre HTTP, ou seja, somente o HTTP não é
suficiente para se trabalhar com Web Services. O SOAP encapsula as mensagens enviadas entre cliente e servidor, resultando em mais trabalho e causando certa lentidão na transmissão das informações.

Um novo paradigma que tem se tornado uma alternativa viável ao SOAP e bem utilizada em aplicações multicamadas, é o REST (Representational State Transfer).

Uma aplicação RESTFul - termo utilizado para identificar um sistema que segue as ideias REST - combina o uso dos princípios estabelecidos pela técnica do REST como: um protocolo cliente-servidor sem estado (stateless), ou seja, cada mensagem HTTP contém toda a informação necessária para compreender uma requisição; e um conjunto bem definido de operações que se aplica a todos os recursos de tratamento de dados.

As operações de uma aplicação RESTFul se assemelham as operações CRUD na persistência de dados tradicional, são elas: POST, GET, PUT e DELETE.

A implementação de tudo isso depende de muita coisa, linguagem, arquitetura, etc, isso é apenas uma ideia geral.

Bons resumos aqui:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/rest-tutorial/28912
https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-web-services-restful/37387